# Destroy previous setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want a function to set an Ajax and a reload timer.  The code below doesn't destroy the previous function call timer, so each time I invoke it I get another timer.  How can I destroy the previous timer?

```
function initNowPlayingMeta(station) {
    $('#cancion').children().remove();
    $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    var prevNowPlaying = setInterval(function () {
        $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to store your timer reference somewhere outside of local scope (this essentially means declaring it with `var` outside of the function).  Then, clear it with `clearInterval`:

```
var prevNowPlaying = null;

function initNowPlayingMeta(station) {
    if(prevNowPlaying) {
        clearInterval(prevNowPlaying);
    }
    $('#cancion').children().remove();
    $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    prevNowPlaying = setInterval(function () {
        $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Note that (at least in theory according to HTML5) setInterval could return zero, so you should check prevNowPlaying has the initial value and not just that its truthful.

Answer (score 10):

[clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

`clearInterval(prevNowPlaying);`

you will also want to make the prevNowPlaying from previous calls in scope whereever you try to cancel

Comment: This won't work unless your reference is outside the function's local scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly clear the timer.

```
var prevNowPlaying;
function initNowPlayingMeta(station) {
    $('#cancion').children().remove();
    $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    if (prevNowPlaying === undefined) clearInterval(prevNowPlaying);
    prevNowPlaying = setInterval(function () {
        $('#cancion').load('sonando.php?emisora=' + station);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I believe `if (prevNowPlaying === 0)` will fail as an unassigned var is `undefined` or `null`, not `0`

Comment: Eh, forget what I said. I misinterpreted your code. I still don't understand why you want to strict compare to `0` though. setInterval is not guaranteed to return `0` is it?

Comment: Bleh, it should be undefined. I have no idea why I wrote 0 there.

Answer (score 0):

For people who only needs to destroy or stop a previous `setInterval`, not exactly what the question ask (jquery, song, etc)

```js
const previousSetIntervalInstance = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

//every 1 second update the time
function myTimer() {
  const date = new Date();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(previousSetIntervalInstance);
}
```

```html
<h3>setInterval() and clearInterval() demo</h3>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the time</button>
```

Initial source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

When you click on stop the time is not updated anymore

Basically, you need to store the **setInterval** output as **global variable** and pass it to **clearInterval**

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by defining the object as undefined.

```
window.sampleIntervalObject = undefined;
```